# Percentage from total

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multiple-integral

I have a table to calculate percentage of numbers. Below are the numbers in the table. In this table how can I find total of E (2.142785) from totals from column A,B, C??

[click here to see the table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv0uI.png)

Means how can I find 2.142785 from 8198, 491 and 66? What formula I can use to find the percentage of values from total values? Any help would be really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Just apply the same formula in total row that you applied in rest of the rows

Comment: @MathLover I tried it didn't work

Comment: Do you get $3.952915$ in col E of the Total row? That is the right value for the Total row.  $2.14228$ is a simple sum of percentages without accounting for their weight. I do not know the whole context of what you are trying to get to but in general, that is not correct.